# Heroku application error chapter 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi i am at chapter 5 of the ror tutorial and i have problems pushing it onto heroku. 
there was no issues at all, with pushing, until now, when it started showing issues with no cedar app supported - even though i have already created my current app using `heroku create --stack cedar`

Also when i ran the domain in the browswer, it brings me to a page where it says application error.

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Umm.... Did you check the log for details?  If you do so and post the result here, we'll have something to go on.  Usually `heroku logs --tail` is a good place to start.  It's likely you don't have Postgres set up correctly.  Heroku will not run SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DB Connection**

You'll be best running:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

There are two types of error with `heroku` - either you have the standard Rails error, or the typical `Heroku` error (as you're seeing right now).

The `heroku` error is basically the result of having no connection to a workable database. Commonly, this is that you've not created the db (which is done with `heroku run rake db:migrate`), but is also part of not having a workable database

You may wish to consult the [Heroku PostgreSQL docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) on how to resolve this